# VB.Net: Read Table from rtf-File

Tags: vb.net, rtf

I have some RTF-Files with a table. Is there a way to get the content of the table into a datatable? Or is there a way to convert the table to csv?

Comment: If a file can be read then it can obviously be processed in any number of ways. A rich text file is no exception to this. If you know where the file is located in the document then it's just a simple case of reading through until you find it and then start work on converting to what you are looking for. The real issue here is whether you have attempted to write such a process and if so, what problems are you having with it. Maybe you should read the [help] and take the [tour].

Comment: I tried it using the plain text from the file, but the format is nearly not readable for human beings (I have to take the file as it is). Another try was to take a RichTextBox, but there were no columns anymore. My last attempt now is to open the files via Interop.Word.Application, this seems to work for what I need it so far.

Comment: P.S.: no need for the help center or the tour for that question.

Comment: The file is in a Rich Text Format, that means that the whole thing can be read by a human. Have you done any research into the [RTF format](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=10725)? Alternatively, you could try creating a basic RTF with similar elements in that you're going to be reading - you can do that with Ms Word. The reason I put the help centre and tour links in was basically because you've not put any kind of research or attempted to solve the problem with code yourself.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451197/understanding-rtf-and-edit-it-with-vb-net?rq=1) post?

Comment: I researched for hours yesterday and did not find any suitable solution except opening the documents with MS Word. There is no need to tell me, I would not have done any researches, because it is really not true.

Comment: A reason for -1 would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as a part answer only, as it is not complete, but can be used to solve the issue that you have.

From the [document specified in my comment](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=10725) I found this detail...

> **Table Definitions**
>
> There is no RTF table group; instead, tables are specified as paragraph properties. A table is represented as a sequence of table rows. A table row is a contiguous series of paragraphs partitioned into cells. The table row begins with the **\trowd** control word and ends with the **\row** control word. Every paragraph that is contained in a table row must have the **\intbl** control word specified or inherited from the previous paragraph. A cell may have more than one paragraph in it; the cell is terminated by a cell mark (the **\cell** control word), and the row is terminated by a row mark (the **\row** control word). Table rows can also be positioned. In this case, every paragraph in a table row must have the same positioning controls (see the  controls on the Positioned Objects and Frames subsection of this Specification. Table properties may be inherited from the previous row; therefore, a series of table rows may be introduced by a single .

You can find this detail from page 93 onward and does seem to provide the bulk of what you need to know.

From this point you should read the file into a string and then search it for each subsequent occurrence of `\trowd` (allowing for the closing `\row` command). This should allow the traversal of all tables within the RTF document. Using this method, and by analysing data within the table, you should be able to ascertain what is important to your requirements.

Comment: This helps, thank you. This will be another sleepless night, because the documents I will have to parse are full of controls and groups (for example, every row starts like {{\trowd ) and in every row there are uncountable groups starting with {{ and a bunch of controls per group - unfortunately, \intbl and \cell are somewhere in the line. Smells like a recursive function... I will take your answer to code this in the next days. For the moment, my version with opening MSWord is very slow, but running.

Comment: `.IndexOf` and `.SubString` are your friend!  ;o)